# How to send success response message using express-graphql?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, graphql, express-graphql

im new to graphql and using express-graphql for my server. I have question on mutation part, how we can send sucsess message if some operation (lika changing password) is succeeded, here is my mutation fields for change password

```
changePassword: {
  type: UserType,
  args: {
    id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
    password: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
    newPassword: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
  },
  resolve(parent, args) {
    return User.findById({ _id: args.id })
      .then(async resp => {
        const checkPassword = await comparePassword(args.password, resp.password);
        if (checkPassword) {
          return resp;
        } else {
          throw new Error('WRONG_PASSWORD');
        }
      })
      .then(async resp => {
        const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(args.newPassword);
        await User.updateOne({ _id: args.id }, { $set: { password: hashedPassword }});
        return resp
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
        return err;
      });
  },
},
```

where or how i could achieve my intention?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. The type for your field is `UserType` so you should return a user. If you want to return a message instead, change the type to a `GraphQLString` instead.

Comment: Do you need shomethings like this?`{
        statusCode: 200,
        body: ....
    };`